# Phoenix dynamic classnames Phoenix.HTML

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to join a dynamic classname name with a static one.

```
<div class=<%="#{getClass(app.status)} two" %>
```

This results in

```
<div class="one" two>
```

Instead of

```
<div class="one two">
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `<div class="<%= getClass(app.status) %> two">`

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using Phoenix within Elixir, this is the way to:

`<div class={"fixed-left #{if @current_user do 'login-page' end}"}>`

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer that worked for me (using .heex templates).

Comment: just a heads up if your class looks like this `class=""` change it to `class={""}` it needs to be wrapped with curly brackets.
i just spent an hour trying to figure out why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<div class="<%= getClass(app.status)} %> two">`.
`<%= %>` evaluate Elixir code and inject result into any part of HTML.
You can inject value inside HTML tag:

```
<div>
  <%= @user_name %>
</div>
```

Or into any HTML attributes

```
<a class="btn <%= if(@alert, do: "btn-danger", else: "btn-primary") %>">...</a>
```

Or set HTML attribute

```
<button class="btn btn-success" <%= if(@disable_button, do: "disabled", else: "tooltip=\"button is working\"") %>">...</button>
```

Comment: Into HTML attributes = ```expected closing `"` for attribute value```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it either like this:

```
<div class={"#{getClass(app.status)} two"}>
<div class={"fixed-left #{if @current_user, do: "login-page"}"}>
```

Which is in my opinion slightly more idiomatic than the code posted by JuliSmz. Note the use of a string (`"login-page"`) instead of a charlist (`'login-page'`) and also the shorter `if` without `end`.

Or I wouldn't mess with string concatenation at all and pass a list like this:

```
<div class={[getClass(app.status), "two"]}>
<div class={["fixed-left", (if @current_user, do: "login-page")]}>
```

The wee bonus of this approach is that we get `<div class="fixed-left">` instead of `<div class="fixed-left ">` when `@current_user` is `nil`.

See the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#sigil_H/2) for more information.

Note that both of the approaches are available only in HEEx (`.html.heex` files or `~H` sigil) which is available since [Phoenix 1.6](https://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/phoenix-1.6-released) and therefore neither of these was valid in the time of OP asking the original question. Without HEEx (in EEx), I would do it like sbacarob and CarefreeSlacker proposed, i.e.:

```
<div class="<%= getClass(app.status) %> two">
<div class="fixed-left <%= if @current_user, do: "login-page" %>">
```